# Return an offset cell value, where last occurrence in range is matched

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a worksheet like this:

```
    ||  A     |  B    |  C  |
 ---++--------+-------+-----|
 ---++--------+-------+-----|
  1 ||  1     |  a    |     |
  2 ||  2     |  b    |     |
  3 ||  3     |  X    |     |
  4 ||  5     |  d    |     |
  5 ||  7     |  X    |     |
  6 ||  8     |  f    |     |
  7 ||  11    |  g    |     |
  8 ||        |       |     |
  9 ||        |       |     |
```

In cell D1, I need a formula that will return `7`. It should return `7`, because `7` is in the cell to the left of last occurrence of value `X` in column B.

I have been trying with `VLOOKUP`, `OFFSET`, `MATCH` and other built ins, but I can't do it.

I would prefer to do it with built in functions if this is possible.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Why 7 and not 5 for the last occurrence of d? You should provide more data in your example

Comment: Do you mean "X" in your comment rather than "d"?  If you can return 5 (the row number) I am sure I could suss it from there.  It's the "last occurrence" part that I can't figure.

Comment: after my answer was submitted the additional requirement to do everything in one cell was added. That is an important requirement. The only other way is to use a pivot table

Comment: To me, the requirement was always in the question. see: "In cell D1".  I didn't explicitly say "don't add columns" because I believe it to be clear enough.  Column C is out of scope!  If it's not possible in a single formula then at least I will find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=index(A:A;max(arrayformula(row(B:B)*(B:B="X"))))
```

Comment: @Jon: perhaps you can flag it as such, so that other people can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

In column C you will need to put into each cell the folowing formula:

```
    =if(countif(B:B,B1)=countif(B$1:B1,B1),"Last_"&B1,"Not Last")
```

Explanation:

- The first countif() tells you how many cells have that letter in Column B
- The second countif() tells you how many are between the top of the column and that row.
- If the two countif()'s give you the same number that row has the last occurrence for the letter so return "Last_"&letter. If they are not equal return "Not Last"

In column D use offset and match to return the value in column1 that has the value "Last_X" in column C. Note:vlookup() for this step would also work if the columns were in a different order.

Comment: countif(B:B,B1) = 1. countif(B$1:B1,B1) = 1.  The first row would return "Last_X".

Comment: I think your formula should have been: `=if(countif(B:B,B1)=countif(B$1:B1,B1),"Last_"&B1,"Not Last")`.  Thanks for your help, but adding a column isn't the answer. I should have been more specific and said I require a single formula.

Comment: fixed typo in the original formula

Comment: after my answer was submitted the additional requirement to do everything in one cell was added. That is an important requirement. The only other way is to use a pivot table

Comment: To me, the requirement was always in the question. see: "In cell D1". I didn't explicitly say "don't add columns" because I believe it to be clear enough. Column C is out of scope! If it's not possible in a single formula then at least I will find out.